# I can't open admin url and store url

Tags: magento2

I've successfully installed `Magento` on `WAMP server` but I can't access admin panel and store.

[image: you can se the image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to enter below command one by one :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```